# Error is thrown when removing tab from tabcontrol

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I have an OwnerDrawFixed tabcontrol.. So, when I try to remove a specific tab from this tabcontrol with this code:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To TabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1
TabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(i)
Next i
```

it shows me an error like:

> Invalid argument value of '1' is not valid for 'index'

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

> Invalid argument value of '1' is not valid for 'index'

The actual error is because there probably isn't a `TabPage` at that index. Since you are looping through and removing `TabPages`, you need to `Step` in the loop as you are removing items. This prevents the loop from getting out of wack with the index.

Since you are removing all `TabPages` anyways you could call the `Clear` method, **but please do not do this.** The clear method will work `TabControl1.TabPages.Clear()`, but it will leave the object hanging around eating up memory freely. Instead remove the objects properly.

```
     While tabControl1.TabCount > 0
        TabControl1.TabPages(0).Dispose()
     End While
```

This will ensure that the objects are properly disposed of be marked for deletion (cleaned up by garbage collector).